# ElasticSearch - Build Java Client querying from Map

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using the latest version of ElasticSearch. I have a JSON document like this.

```
{
    "id": "RRRZe32",
    "metadata": {
         "published": "2010-07-29T18:11:43.000Z",
         "codeId": "AChdUxnsuRyoCo7roK6gqZSg",
         "codeTitle": "something"
    }
    "sellers":["abc", "zyx", "pqr"]
}
```

I just want to check whether any such document is available in my index. I have converted this JSON document into `Map<String, Object> queryList`.

Can you please help me in figuring out how can I build a query using JAVA API QueryBuiler?

Comment: you can check by id (assuming this is the index id ) : `http://IP:PORT/INDEXPATH/RRRZe32`

Comment: As data arrives from a publisher, I need to make such query from my java program.

Comment: What does "any such" mean here - are you trying to search by id or something within metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("indexName", "typeName", "id")
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/get.html)